# Loading spinner in button showing even when loading prop is set to false

Tags: svelte

I have a `Button` component with a boolean loading prop. When loading is true, I show a loading spinner.

However, I am now using that button to load more stuff in a paginated query. When the query is loading, the button should show the loading indicator, and it does, but when loading then stops, the loading indicator should be removed. However it does not.

I have made a minimal working example in the svelte REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/395b273f3e384af3b5351f7469837973?version=3.42.6). When you press the button it starts the loading state, and removes it after 1 second. However as you can see the loading indicator is still there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `transition:fade` directive doesn't play well with nested, conditionally rendered SVGs in svelte (remove those transitions and everything works as intended).

So, you can get around this with a hacky programmatically triggered $destroy, or I guess you could replace the fades with simple CSS transitions.

Anyway this is my proposed "solution" :
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/71c4a258db8b45269f93b6cbf61e8c75?version=3.42.6)